# Login page with background image have scrollbars, how to remove them?

Tags: html, css, sass

How to remove scrollbars from page?

I added the image as background with next css code:

```
.login-background {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

I check does page have some margin, paddings or something but noting...

This is CSS of login page:

```
.login-page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.login-wrapper {
  align-self: center;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.login-background {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

I cannot fix this by next apporch:

```
body { overflow: hidden }
```

Need better solution.

```html
<div className="login-page">
  <picture>
    <source srcSet={mobileImg} media="(max-width: 700px)" />
    <source srcSet={tabletImg} media="(min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 1300px)" />
    <img src={desktopImg} className="login-background" alt="background" />
  </picture>
  <div className="login-wrapper">
    <div className="login-logo-wrapper">
      <img className="login-logo" src={logo} alt="logo" />
      <p className="login-logo-text">TEX</p>
    </div>
    <a href="/auth/google" className="login-button">
      <label className="login-button-label">Log in with Google</label>
      <span className="svgIcon">
            <img src={google} className="google-logo" alt="google auth" />
          </span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're looking for `overflow: hidden`, not `overlay: hidden`. Also, please post your HTML; it's impossible to answer this question without it.

Comment: I updated the post

Answer (score 1):

Just make your "background-image" display:block

```css
.login-background {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  object-fit: cover;
  display:block;
}
```

Images are by default `display:inline`. This means that its in the text-flow and adds space for letters like "j" and "g" (these are below the baseline)

Comment: Hey, It wasn't help.

Comment: sorry, forgot to add display:block. I've adjusted my answer.

Comment: I tried with `display:block` but result is the same. 
you can try here trough inspect element: https://sourcing-dev.tamedia.ch/login 
result is the same. But thanks on try!